# What is the 'tail-hash' in Cryptonight?

Tags: cryptonight

I understand cryptonight uses keccak and aes. I don't understand what the tail-hash means though.

Comment: You must have read what I said on IRC - there's a randomly chosen hash function used at the end to process the output, one of four.

Answer (score 1):

There is a diagram on page 6 and 7 [here](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt) which labels the last (tail) hash as "Chosen hash".

And described:

```
Then, the 2 low-order bits of the first byte of the state are used to
select a hash function: 0=BLAKE-256 [BLAKE], 1=Groestl-256 [GROESTL],
2=JH-256 [JH], and 3=Skein-256 [SKEIN]. The chosen hash function is
then applied to the Keccak state, and the resulting hash is the
output of CryptoNight.
```